# Error when using Scanner input

Tags: java, printing, java.util.scanner, eclipse-mars

I am trying to take input from my file into my class. I am testing it out like this:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    System.out.print(input);
```

However, the console prints this out:

```
    java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q?\E][infinity string=\Q?\E]
```

If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it :D

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file content, line by line, instead of simply printing the scanner object. Maybe something like this:

```
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
  String line = input.nextLine();
  System.out.println (line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I just realized how dumb of a question that was LOL, but I appreciate you explaining it to me in terms :)